# Compilation taking too much RAM?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, ram

I'm trying to compile a custom Linux Kernel but when I get to the last step and compiling VMLinux.o, the make process gets killed and shows error137, which means that I'm out of memory.
I'm on 4gb RAM, a core2duo and have compiled Kernels before without any issues.
The issue started when I was editing make menu config so I must have done something that makes the compilation require more RAM.
I've already tried ''make -j1'' to compile the Kernel but I still get the same issue.

Comment: For having built linux kernels with much less resources, I'm left surprised… Of course, you launch your build under some tty. (No DE running) ?

Comment: I couldn't launch the GUI since I messed up my first Kernel config and Linux didn't recognize my keyboard, hence why I was editing the Kernel in Linux Mint only to find myself stuck in this situation

Comment: I fail to understand What kernel you are booting on (some possibly broken one ? Some older one ?…) I still fail to understand in which conditions you launch your make ? And at the end of the day you suggest that only your .config would be borken ?

Comment: I boot from whatever Kernel that is on my Linux Mint live USB-stick. I'm building my distro from Linux Mint.

Comment: Then reinstall a working kernel on your system from the live-USB and restart your config fiddlings after booting on that kernel.

Comment: @MC68020 why? the linux kernel is definitely meant for cross-building. You practically never built the kernel on the target system (would be quite interesting to build a linux kernel on a 20€ internet router)

Comment: @MarcusMüller : in order not to build under a live_USB booted system which uses ram for file storage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As a C++ developer: 4GB is not that much when linking larger objects, so yeah, this might be totally expected.

Try adding some swap space; you're only going to need it very punctually, I'd guess.

Comment: Thanks @markus!
 I'm doing it from an live image of Linux Mint so I don't have a swap partition but that hasn't been a problem until now.

Comment: Oh come on Markus… you know how much Linus despises C++… 4GB should be *much* more than enough to build the linux kernel. :-P

Comment: :D I'm afraid Linus doesn't write the linker ;)

Comment: Even so, the linker shouldn’t need 4GiB of RAM to link the kernel.

Comment: Won't a live image mount a ramdisk as the primary storage?  That will consume a lot of the 4GB memory with files, leaving less for the compiler to use.